# Regular Expression: avoiding keywords matching

Tags: regex

With the regular expression `id: ([a-z]|[A-Z]+)\\w*` I can recognize all the identifiers starting with a letter. Is there a way using a single regular expression to exclude some specific identifiers (for example a keyword in a programming language)?

Image that I have the following input line:

> car zed var for while airplane

and `var` `for` and `while` are keywords of my programming language. The regular expression should match only `car`, `zed` and `airplane`.

Is this possible? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sure, but there are some problem for which regex are not the best of all possible solutions or at least not ideal for implementing the whole solution.

Answer (score 2):

tested with grep:

```
kent$  echo "car zed var for while airplane"|grep -Po '(?!\bfor|\bwhile|\bvar)\b\w+'
car
zed
airplane
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use word anchors and alternation:</strike>

```
\b(var|for|while)\b
```

This can only match the exact same keyword you wrote.

**Edit: completely misread your question:**

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b(?!(?:for|var|while)\b)\w+\b");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    }
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
\b                # Assert position at a word boundary
(?!               # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   (?:            # Match the regular expression below
                  # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         for      # Match the characters “for” literally
      |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         var      # Match the characters “var” literally
      |           # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         while    # Match the characters “while” literally
   )
   \b             # Assert position at a word boundary
)
\w                # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
   +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b                # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Comment: yes surely it matches var, for and airplane but not car and zed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but this is the opposite of what was asked -- these words should *not* be matched.

Comment: @GuidoRanzuglia I misread your question because I was talking on the phone - Men are not good for multitasking :)..

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! Especially to FailedDev and to Kent. Theirs solutions are working quite well!

Comment: +1 But may I make a suggestion? Instead of writing a condensed regex and a separate, expanded (regexbuddy) explanation, why not write the regex in free-spacing mode with comments from the get-go? The code that gets this regex is thus, self-commenting and much more maintainable. This also helps in the crafting of the regex in the first place. I do this even for javascript and convert the regex to the `/.../g` format once the regex is fully crafted. I _strongly_ believe that all non-trivial regexes should be written in free-spacing mode with lots-o-comments and proper indentation. Just sayin'...

Comment: @ridgerunner Yeah, I would try to change the style of the answer too. I also find free spacing preferable!